# Fitting table to the whole page

Tags: tables

How to fit the table into the page size in revtex 4.1

```
\documentclass[%
  aip,
  jap,%
  amsmath,amssymb,
  reprint,%
  ]{revtex4-1}

 \draft

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{times}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
          singlelinecheck = false}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{\label{}}

\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{l*9 {c}}
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How you mean "whole page" ? Its width to be equal text width? Or text height and be only it on the page?

Comment: Note that `\draft` is deprecated by `revtex4-1`; also `\caption` is *not* to be used with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
I assume, that  with "whole page" you mean over both columns in two column text. In this case you need to use

\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}

however table will be moved to the next page. There is one more limitations. At use of `tabularx` and columns of type `X`, the width of this columns is wrong interpreted: each take width of whole table. So it is better to use `tabular*` and columns `p{...}` or others (c, l, r, m{...}).

```
\documentclass[%
  aip,
  jap,%
  amsmath,amssymb,
  reprint,%
  ]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{times,bm}

\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{table*}[htb]
\centering
    \caption{}
\label{}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{l*9{p{0.08\hsize}}}
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\end{tabular*}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[4-8]
    \begin{table*}[htb]
\centering
    \caption{}
\label{}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{l*9{p{0.08\hsize}}}
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\end{tabular*}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[9-13]
    \begin{table*}[htb]
\centering
    \caption{}
\label{}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{l*9{p{0.08\hsize}}}
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
System & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\end{tabular*}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I cannot comment all other packages.. what is the solution in that case?

Comment: You just use them. For showing a solution they are not necessary. They will not change anything in your use. I was on the way and on my laptop I haven't installed them ...

Comment: @user87834, after installing `revtex` package and seeing, what it produce, I rewrote my answer with considering assumption, that you have two column text and you like to have tables, which span both columns.  Now are used all packages from your MWE, however with tiny difference: each is only one-time loaded in preamble.

Comment: The extra square appears above and on the sides. that is not required. How to remove them.

Comment: Just comment or remove `\usepackage{showframe}`. Its function is only to show page layout (by it is shown, that table fit text width) . Box above show place for page header. In a real page it has not to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the code it worked very well. But if the number is increased  from 9 to 10 in the code \begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{l*9{p{0.08\hsize}}}. it shows the error "Package array Error : Illegal pream-token (0) : 'c' used"

Comment: If the number is less than 10, this , somehow "reduced" used syntax works. However, the correct syntax for this line is `\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{l*{9}{p{0.08\hsize}}}` (note: number 10 is in curly braces). If you will in it replace `9` with `10`, it will work.